# Which one to use for payments on Drupal website, LM_Paypal or Ubercart?

Tags: php, drupal, e-commerce

Im a new Drupal user . I want to be able to handle payments on my Drupal website. I would like to know which would be a better option, LM_Paypal module or the Ubercart module ?.
Does the Ubercart module have any specific advantages over the LM_Paypal module or vice versa ?

Please help.
Thank You

Answer (score 2):

They're quite different -- Ubercart is a full fledged shopping cart with dozens (hundreds?) of add on modules for things like coupons, shipping, different payment gateways, wishlists, inventory, etc.  If you just need simple subscriptions or buy buttons, lm_paypal might be for you.  But if you want (or think you will grow into) a full online store with additional features, you probably want to start with ubercart out of the gate.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry cannot give you a comparison as have only used one, LM_Paypal. However installed over a year ago, done at least two Drupal upgrades since then and it is still functioning fine.

Answer (score 0):

I've used Ubercart, eCommerece and LM Paypal. For my needs (which are basic subscriptions and donations + small purchases) I stuck with LM Paypal since it's VERY easy to understand and setup. The others are much more complex for beginners and can take some time and head scratching to get up and running.

If you just need handle incoming payments I'd recommend LM Paypal.